# How to import aspx pages across different Visual Studio solutions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm very newer developing .NET web applications. Before read, I'm so sorry if I'm not  able to explain correctly or if I'm confusing about something of .NET. Hope all of you can give me some light in .NET environment.

**Context:** We have two different solutions because the original idea was to develop two different applications with no common pages or content between them. Now, we need to have one of the aspx page that is in the solution1 inside the solution2 (and probably more in the future) because it's common between them.The idea is not to have two different maintenance of the same page. This two solutions have only one project inside them and each project has his own master page.

- Solution1:
  -Project1
- Solution2:
  -Project2

**Question 1:** Is it possible to import or use complete aspx page across the solutions? I mean, I know that is possible to import aspx files from the project1 into the project2, but doing this way, every change into the original aspx file of project1 means that is needed a new import into project2 (or this is what I think) to have the page up to date. What is the best way to share content between different solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to import a file with "import as a link" feature from one project to the other one, but it returns me a dll error like this: "The type '{0}' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly '{1}' or from assembly '{2}'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name". I'm not sure how to fix it, more specifically how to compile this file with a specific dll. Then, I created an empty third project to test the same but this time with an ascx file and it worked well.

Comment: I suppose that the best way to solve this is create a third project to put in those common files but, anyone knows why it returns me that error or even better how to fix it?

Comment: Yesterday I spent lot of time trying to solve the Assembly name issue, but I was not be able to fix it. To keep what I have I need to be able to import as a link those files that I need of the other project, but having this posted error is not possible. The other thing I have in mind is to use ascx files and start cleaner third project focusing in sharing content between projects. Anyway thanks a lot for trying to help me, if anyone can bring me other advice I would appreciate it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the aspx page which exists in one solution (and version controlled hopefully!), to your other solution by adding it as a linked file.

MSDN explains how Visual Studio allows you to add an item as a link rather than directly adding the file to your project.

By linking to a file, you can capture ongoing changes to a source file without having to manually update a copy whenever changes are made. However, if the underlying file is deleted, the link will be broken.

To create a link to an existing item

1. In Solution Explorer, select the target project.
2. On the Project menu, select Add Existing Item.
3. In the Add Existing Item dialog box, locate and select the project
   item you want to link.
4. From the Open button drop-down list, select Add As Link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_0

Another helpful article by Grant Winney on the topic here:
https://grantwinney.com/visual-studio-add-file-as-link/

Comment: Hi @scotty, thank you a lot for replying. The code behind of the aspx file that I need to import uses classes that are not implemented in the other project (that belongs to the other solution) because that classes don't have sense there. If I import the file as a link I would need to implement that classes? What's the difference between having two projects under the same solution or having two projects in separate projects? Thank you. Victor.

Comment: It would have sense here create third project .NET Server Control or something similar to put there the common files? I'm not sure if this is the purpose of Server Control or .ascx file